# Curl and xargs in piped commands

Tags: bash, awk

I want to process an old database where password are plain text (comma separated ; passwd is the 5th field in the csv file where the database has been exported) to crypt them for further use by dokuwiki. Here is my bash command (grep and sed are there to extract the crypted passwd from curl output) :

```
cat users.csv | awk 'FS="," { print $4 }' | xargs  -l bash -c 'curl -s --data-binary "pass1=$0&pass2=$0" "https://sprhost.com/tools/SMD5.php" -o - ' | xargs  | grep -o '<tt.*tt>' | sed -e 's/tt//g' | sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g'
```

- I get the following comment from xargs

  xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option
- And only the first line of the file is processed, and nothing appends then.

Using the -0 option, and playing around with quotes, doesn't solve anything. Where am I wrong in the command line ? May be a more advanced language will be more adequate to do this.

Thank for help, LM

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you have such a long pipe of commands, it is better to split them if things go wrong. Going through your pipe:

```
cat users.csv |
```

Nothing unexpected there.

```
awk 'FS="," { print $4 }' |
```

You probably wanted to do `awk 'BEGIN {FS=","} { print $4 }'`. Try the first two commands in the pipe and see if they produce the correct answer.

```
xargs  -l bash -c 'curl -s --data-binary "pass1=$0&pass2=$0" "https://sprhost.com/tools/SMD5.php" -o - ' |
```

Nothing wrong there, although there might be better ways to do an MD5 hash.

```
xargs  |
```

What is this xargs doing in the pipe? It should be removed.

```
grep -o '<tt.*tt>' |
```

Note that this will produce two lines:

```
<tt>$1$17ab075e$0VQMuM3cr5CtElvMxrPcE0</tt>
<tt>&lt;your_docuwiki_root&gt;/conf/users.auth.php</tt>
```

which is probably not what you expected.

```
sed -e 's/tt//g' |
sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g'
```

which will remove the html-tags, though

```
sed 's/<tt>//;s/<.tt>//'
```

will do the same.

So I'd say a wrong `awk` and an `xargs` too many.